# Linq expression that would always return true

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I need to pass a parameter to a method that requires an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

How to do I pass an expression that would always return `true`?

Using `obj => true` doesn't work because the framework complains at runtime that it cannot determine the memeber type from the True constant.

Comment: Please provide a complete example, and tell us which provider you're using.

Comment: I think your error is somewhere else. This compiles: `new List<object>().AsQueryable().Where(p => true);`, and the type of the parameter of the `Where` is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Answer (score 13):

If you have a function like this

```
void TakeExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
```

You should call it this way, specifying the T type :

```
TakeExpression<int>(_ => true)
```

It should work.

Comment: Yeah, normally in Linq it is working on a Source Object so it can get its <T> Type from that.

Comment: Exactly, the source type cannot be determined implicitly, so you should pass it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the parameter type you are passing:

```
(object o) => true
```

Or

```
(int a) => true
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the result as follows.

Consider **context** as your DbContext instance and **Entity** as your entity class name.

```
context.Entity.Where(t=> t.EntityID == t.EntityID);
```

By doing this the where clause will always return true and all the data will be shown.

Answer (score -1):

There are two problems here:

1) If you're passing a predicate such that you always want to return true, then it's not much of a predicate. You may be able to omit whatever call you are trying to make.

2) If you want to just return true, you can simple use a more verbose lambda syntax to get what you want:

```
sample.AsQueryable().Where((x) => { return true; });
```

The more verbose syntax allows you to specify closer to an anonymous function while still being an expression.